# Different string.xml files according to app Build Variants

Tags: android, gradle, build-variant

I want to assign a value to a string in string.xml different values depending on the Build Variant/buildType. I imagine something like this:

> ```
> res/values-debug/string.xml
>     <string name="my_string">some debug value</string>
>
> res/values-release/string.xml
>     <string name="my_string">some release value</string>
> ```

but I don't see anything like this out there.
Is this possible?

Comment: This is much easier when you use buildVariant not buildType. In your example `buildType` is used

Comment: interesting, the answers on this page are for build types, not build variants...

Comment: So what would using buildVariant look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's possible!

In your build.gradle you can add something like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Then in your `src` folder in your project you should have a folder called main, add one next to it called `debug`. Den as long as you are building your debug flavour any resources in your debug folder will replace those in main which is the release folder.

Should look like this:

```
src/
    main/
        java/ -- all your java code
        res/
            ...
            values/
                strings.xml
    debug/
        res/
            ...
            values/
                strings.xml
```

EDIT: The approaches from the two other answers works fine as well. But if you have a lot of strings keeping them as xml might be easier to handle.

Comment: I would like to use this approach because then I could also add mipmap folders. I can't get it to work though. I've added to the question to show you what I am doing. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I got it now. I didn't have the directory structure right.

Comment: I'm glad you like this way! I find it very useful to be able to distinguish the two apps, debug and release with icons, names, urls and whatever and this approach does it the best way. :)

Answer (score 19):

It possible via your build.gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue "string", "my_string", "some release value"
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "my_string", "some debug value"
    }
}
```

Then you can just use this value like `@string/my_string` where you want

Comment: And I remove the entry in strings.xml?

Comment: @AlLelopath yes, now you can remove it form xml

Answer (score 3):

```
resValue 'string', '<string_name>', "some string"
```

define different ones in your build.gradle for different build variants/product flavors

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly from **Android Studio**. For example, if you need a different app name for your "staging" flavor, you can (Android Studio v3.5):

- Right click on values folder -> New -> Values resource file
- Select "staging" in the source set menu
- specify strings.xml as filename

At this point Android Studio generates an additional `strings.xml` file for your particular build variant. Edit the created file with your "staging" app name (E.g. MyAppName - Staging)

[image: strings.xml - staging]
[image: strings.xml - production]

build.gradle(app)

```groovy
productFlavors {
        stage {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SITE_URL', '"[staging_link_here]"'
        }
        prod {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SITE_URL', '"[production_link_here]"'
        }
 }
```